# How would I underline an equation with a curly brace and an explanation?

Tags: equations, mathematics

> How would I underline an equation with a curly brace and an explanation?, like I've pictured below?

I've tried to use the `amsmath` package, but the `\underline` directive does not produce the brace and creates ugly space between the `A`, `B` and `=`.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

\underline is not \underbrace. Use

```
 \usepackage{amsmath}
  ..........
 \begin{document}

 \[ \underbrace{A=B}_{\text{Fermat}} \]
  ...........

\end{document}
```